# How Racket streams work in this case?

Tags: stream, scheme, racket, self-reference, sicp

I am currently learning Racket (just for fun) and I stumbled upon this example:

```
(define doubles
   (stream-cons
     1
     (stream-map 
        (lambda (x) 
            (begin
                (display "map applied to: ")
                (display x)
                (newline)
                (* x 2)))
        doubles)))
```

It produces *1 2 4 8 16 ...*

I do not quite understand how it works.

So it creates *1* as a first element; when I call `(stream-ref doubles 1)` it creates a second element which is obviously *2*.

Then I call `(stream-ref doubles 2)` which should force creating the third element so it calls `stream-map` for a stream which already has 2 elements – `(1 2)` – so it should produce `(2 4)` then and append this result to the stream.

Why is this `stream-map` always applied to the *last* created element? How it works?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might be interested in [SICP lesson about streams](https://youtu.be/a2Qt9uxhNSM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard trick that makes it possible for lazy streams to be defined in terms of their previous element. Consider a stream as an infinite sequence of values:

```
s = x0, x1, x2, ...
```

Now, when you `map` over a stream, you provide a function and produce a new stream with the function applied to each element of the stream:

```
map(f, s) = f(x0), f(x1), f(x2), ...
```

But what happens when a stream is defined in terms of a mapping over itself? Well, if we have a stream `s = 1, map(f, s)`, we can expand that definition:

```
s = 1, map(f, s)
  = 1, f(x0), f(x1), f(x2), ...
```

Now, when we actually go to evaluate the second element of the stream, `f(x0)`, then `x0` is clearly `1`, since we defined the first element of the stream to be `1`. But when we go to evaluate the third element of the stream, `f(x1)`, we need to know `x1`. Fortunately, we just evaluated `x1`, since it is `f(x0)`! This means we can “unfold” the sequence one element at a time, where each element is defined in terms of the previous one:

```
f(x) = x * 2

s = 1, map(f, s)
  = 1, f(x0), f(x1), f(x2), ...
  = 1, f(1),  f(x1), f(x2), ...
  = 1, 2,     f(x1), f(x2), ...
  = 1, 2,     f(2),  f(x2), ...
  = 1, 2,     4,     f(x2), ...
  = 1, 2,     4,     f(4),  ...
  = 1, 2,     4,     8,     ...
```

This knot-tying works because streams are evaluated lazily, so each value is computed on-demand, left-to-right. Therefore, each previous element has been computed by the time the subsequent one is demanded, and the self-reference doesn’t cause any problems.